# forkJoin() is not emitting called while its participants are emitting fine

Tags: angular, rxjs

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-v6m7nr)

In following code, `this.form.valueChanges` and `this.form.get('name').valueChanges` is emitting fine. But `forkJoin` of these not working. Can someone pls advice?

```
export class AppComponent  {
  name = 'Angular';
  form = this.formBuilder.group({
    name:'test'
  })
  constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder){

  }

  ngOnInit(){

    forkJoin(this.form.valueChanges, this.form.get('name').valueChanges)
    .subscribe(x=>alert(x))//NOT working

    this.form.valueChanges.subscribe((x)=>alert(JSON.stringify(x)));//fine 
    this.form.get('name').valueChanges.subscribe((x)=>alert(x))//fine 
  }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`forkJoin` emits only after all its source Observables emitted at least once and they all complete.

And this is the problem you have because `valueChanges` is internally implemented as 
a `Subject` that is never completed.

You could for example prepend each source Observable with `take(1)` that makes it complete after the first emission or maybe you're in fact looking for `combineLatest(...).pipe(take(1))`.